# OpenGL ES 1 multi-texturing with different uv coordinates

Tags: ios, opengl-es, multitexturing

I need to render an object using multi-texturing but both the textures have different uv coordinates for same object. One is normal map and other one is light map.

Please provide any useful material regarding this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In OpenGL ES 2 you use shaders anyway. So you're completely free to use whatever texture coordinates you like. Just introduce an additional attribute for the second texture cooridnate pair and delegate this to the fragment shader, as usual:

```
...
attribute vec2 texCoord0;
attribute vec2 texCoord1;

varying vec2 vTexCoord0;
varying vec2 vTexCoord1;

void main()
{
    ...
    vTexCoord0 = texCoord0;
    vTexCoord1 = texCoord1;
}
```

And in the fragment shader use the respective coordinates to access the textures:

```
...
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
...
varying vec2 vTexCoord0;
varying vec2 vTexCoord1;

void main()
{
    ... = texture2D(tex0, vTexCoord0);
    ... = texture2D(tex1, vTexCoord1);
}
```

And of course you need to provide data to this new attribute (using `glVertexAttribPointer`). But if all this sounds very alien to you, then you should either delve a little deeper into GLSL shaders or you actually use OpenGL ES 1. In this case you should retag your question and I will update my answer.

**EDIT:** According to your update for OpenGL ES 1 the situation is a bit different. I assume you already know how to use a single texture and specify texture coordinates for this, otherwise you should start there before delving into multi-texturing.

With `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTUREi)` you can activate the ith texture unit. All following operations related to texture state only refer to the ith texture unit (like `glBindTexture`, but also `glTexEnv` and `gl(En/Dis)able(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`).

For specifying the texture coordinates you still use the `glTexCoordPointer` function, as with single texturing, but with `glCientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTUREi)` you can select the texture unit to which following calls to `glTexCoordPointer` and `glEnableClientAttrib(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)` refer.

So it would be something like:

```
//bind and enable textures
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, <second texture>);
glTexEnv(<texture environment for second texture>);   //maybe, if needed
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, <first texture>);
glTexEnv(<texture environment for first texture>);   //maybe, if needed
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//set texture coordinates
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glTexCoordPointer(<texCoords for second texture>);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glTexCoordPointer(<texCoords for first texture>);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

//other arrays, like glVertexPointer, ...

glDrawArrays(...)/glDrawElements(...);

//disable arrays
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

//disable textures
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

The reason I set the parameters for the second texture before the first texture is only so that after setting them we end up with texture unit 0 active. I think I have already seen drivers making problems when drawing and another unit than unit 0 was active. And it's always a good idea to leave a more or less clean state at the end, which means the default texture unit (`GL_TEXTURE0`) active, as otherwise code that doesn't care about multi-texturing could get problems.

**EDIT:** If you use immediate mode (`glBegin/glEnd`) instead of vertex arrays, then you don't use `glTexCoordPointer`, of course. In this case you also don't need `glClientAttribTexture`, of course. You just need to use `glMultiTexCoord(GL_TEXTUREi, ...)` with the appropriate texture unit (`GL_TEXTURE0`, `GL_TEXTURE1`, ...) instead of `glTexCoord(...)`. But if I'm informed correctly, OpenGL ES doesn't have immediate mode, anyway.

Comment: thanks for your feedback.now i have retaged my question with opengles . kindly provide the solution how to do this in OpenGL ES 1.please provide any example code if available. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rocksvick You have added the opengl-es tag, but you didn't remove the opengl-es-2.0 tag, nor changed the title. So do you need only an OpenGL ES 1.1 solution or an OpenGL ES 2.0 solution or both?

Comment: As per your guidelines i have removed opengl-es-2.0 tag and changed the title . Kindly provide the solution and any example code if available . Thanks