# How to do multi-texturing using open gl es 1.1 in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1, multitexturing

**What I have done**

Currently in my Android app I am drawing  rectangles with two different textures 
There  is a fade in (changes the alpha ) animation for one texture (for the second one ) is given.

**What I Want.**

I want to use multi - texturing thus  draw both texture in a single rectangle.
But I am not able to find any helping stuffs that using opengl es 1.1 for multi texturing with android.

Please any one help me to do multi texturing

Here is my code

```
    firstGanColorVert.position(0);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, VERTEX_SIZE, firstGanColorVert);        
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, firstGaneshaTexture);          


    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();            
    gl.glTranslatef(this.x,this.y ,0);  

    textCordPointer(gl);        
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);   


    fadeAnimation();

    secondGanColorVert.position(0);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, VERTEX_SIZE, secondGanColorVert);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, secondGaneshaTexture);         


    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();            
    gl.glTranslatef(this.x,this.y ,0);          
    textCordPointer(gl);        
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
```

Comment: Can you define 'combine'? Maybe put up some mockup images of what result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Tim Hi, Thanks for the reply , I edited my question, What I am looking for is multi texturing...

Comment: This might be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/7754860/310455

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much help this will be, but the [Imagination Technologies' SDK](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp) includes source for quite a number example programs for OpenGL ES. If you download that (free registeration required) in the "SDK3.0/Examples/Intermediate" subdirectory there is a multitexture example. (I only opted for the "Windows emulation" option but android was also listed). Might be worth looking at.